# SQL update multiple rows on specific ID's

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am trying to write a query to update several rows of my SQL table at once.  Below is the code I have tried, and it doesn't appear to be proper SQL as it doesn't work. Is there a way to accomplish this is one query?

```
$query = "UPDATE table_names
          SET Name='Bob' WHERE ID=7 
          SET Name='Mike' WHERE ID=34"
```

Comment: One `UPDATE` statement for each separate `ID` value ...

Comment: Do not make things so complicated. Just use one `UPDATE` for each ID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is with a `case` expression:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET    name = CASE id WHEN 7  THEN 'Bob'
                      WHEN 34 THEN 'Mike'
              END
WHERE  id IN (7, 34)
```

Comment: Interesting.  Is the last line just precautionary?  It seems redundant.

Comment: @Tortooga not at all - without it, you would update the names with all the other `id`s with `null`s!

Comment: Thanks!  This solution works.  I will give it a shot and see if having a query with lots of cases like this has performance issues.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is more practival than "case when" I found and you can update as many columns as wanted

```
UPDATE searches_group_library
SET compiled_query = new_val.compiledq
FROM (VALUES 
        (28, 'fakecompilation'),
        (57, 'fakecompilation2')
) new_val (id, compiledq)
WHERE new_val.id = searches_group_library.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest doing this with 2 queries:

```
UPDATE table_names
SET Name='Bob' WHERE ID=7

UPDATE table_names
SET Name='Mike' WHERE ID=34
```

you can do this in one query, but I don't think it is the right way:

```
INSERT table_name 
KEYS (id, `name`)
VALUES (7, 'Bob'), (34, 'Mike')
ON DUPLICATE Key UPDATE
```

something like that, if you really look for one query find how to use the "on duplicate"

but I suggest using 2 queries.