# How to update multiple ids at once

Tags: mysql, sql

I just began learning how to code w/ SQL. I am following a tutorial on Codeacedemy.com

Here is something I wrote for the fun of it, a simple date base:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (id INTEGER, name TEXT, year INTEGER);
INSERT INTO employees (id, name, year) VALUES (1, 'Dave', 2010);
INSERT INTO employees (id, name, year) VALUES (2, 'Karen', 2001);
INSERT INTO employees (id, name, year) VALUES (3, 'Joe', 2009);
INSERT INTO employees (id, name, year) VALUES (4, 'Larry', 2013);
INSERT INTO employees (id, name, year) VALUES (5, 'Tammy', 2015);
INSERT INTO employees (id, name, year) VALUES (6, 'Samantha', 2005);
INSERT INTO employees (id, name, year) VALUES (7, 'Karen', 2010);
INSERT INTO employees (id, name, year) VALUES (8, 'Rick', 2011);

ALTER TABLE employees ADD COLUMN gender TEXT;

UPDATE employees
set gender = 'Male'
where id = 1;

SELECT * FROM employees;
```

Is there a way that I can update multiple rows at once using their id? For example, I can use id 1, 3, 5, 8 and they'll all be updated to 'male'.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL WHERE ID IN (id1, id2, ..., idn)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803472/sql-where-id-in-id1-id2-idn)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159616/sql-update-multiple-rows-on-specific-ids?rq=1

Comment: Thank you, link was very helpful!

Answer (score 24):

This for using where clause :

```
 UPDATE employees SET gender = 'Male' WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

If you want update all rows in table then:

```
UPDATE employees SET gender = 'Male'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the same thing, but for the ID's you can use ID's in

Like this:

```
 ....
 where id in (1,2,3);
```

You can also write a nested query inside `IN`.

For more details on how to write `IN` you can refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).